# Docker commit alterations of a built image

Tags: docker

I 've built an image using A Dockerfile and I've noticed an error in the created image.  I've then run the image and fixed the error.

Now I would like to know if the correct flow is to commit the changes to the built image, or create a new image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options:

- Fix your `Dockerfile` and rebuild it, that's the reason we have `Dockerfile`, from which an expected/correct image can be built by anybody at anywhere
- Run a container from your incorrect image and fix it, then commit back to the image. You can choose this option when your building process is extremely long but what you need is to do a quick/small fix. But remember to always fix `Dockerfile`, which is the "definetion" of your image and I believe you don't want to leave any kind of "bug" in it.

Answer (score 1):

If a working image is all you want, then committing it is fine. You will then get a new image that includes your fix.

However, the benefit of having a Dockerfile is that your build is reproducible, so if your ever want to share the image with someone else, or foresee yourself rebuilding it, you should probably maintain the Dockerfile.